# BSS84 behaviour

Tags: mosfet

Team,

I am experiencing strange behaviour on a BSS84 (Taiwan Semi P/N BSS84 RFG) and wondered if anyone could explain the issues I'm seeing or whether it's just a bad batch. Pin connections have been checked and double checked.

Circuit is setup per this schematic, and EN flips between 4.6VDC with switch open and 5.0VDC with switch closed.

Can anyone suggest a reason for this or have I got a bad batch?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk1odD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have swapped Drain and source of M2. So, the bulk diode of M2 is conducting and making EN 4.6V instead of EN going to 0V when M2 is OFF

Comment: despite me double checking you might have a point here. I'll check tonight and eat humble pie if you're right.

Comment: You were correct, Drain and Source were cross connected. All is well, thanks for your help

Comment: You can also choose to accept the answer. Please see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

The [BSS84 MOSFET](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/308/1/BSS84_D-1658817.pdf) has a value in the data sheet that tells you how much leakage current flows from source to drain when the gate-source voltage is zero volts. It's called \$I_{DSS}\$ and, it is quoted as being 15 μA but, under warmer conditions, could be as high as 60 μA. If 15 μA current was flowing into the 100 kΩ load resistor it would produce a voltage at the drain of 1.5 volts with respect to ground/0 volts.

This doesn't fully account for the 4.6 volts you are seeing but it should tell you that if you expected the voltage across the 100 kΩ resistor to be zero when the MOSFET is disabled, you might need to think again.

You might also look at how you implement SW1. For instance, if using an opto-coupler, it will also have leakage current (when supposedly off) and, that current will flow through the 220 kΩ resistor and potentially partially activate the BSS84. Both these things combined will lead to what you see.

Comment: Generous datasheet limits notwithstanding, the typical leakage current at room temperature is so low the voltage across the 100kΩ would be hard to measure.

Comment: The data sheet doesn't give a typical value and, if you were designing this would you work to a typical value if you wanted low volt-drop across the output resistor when the MOSFET is deactivated. The OP talks about a batch so, he's probably interested in putting this circuit into production and, if so, I know which limit I'd be interested in.